# Continue outside of loop error despite it being inside the loop

Tags: java, loops, continue

I can't run this code because of a continue outside loop error.

I have looked online and found that people had issues due to having an extra semi-colon. I don't have that issue but yet I still get this error.

```
public class GuessingGame {

     int random;

    public void generateNumber() 
    {
       //The following lines generate and output a random number between 1 and 10
        random = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;

    }

   //Write the guess() method below 
   public void guess()
   {
       //Use scanner to accept a user input 
       //Create a new scanner object to receive user input
          Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter you guess between 1 to 10");
          int guess = sc.nextInt();

          //write your code below
       if (guess == random){
           System.out.println("You guessed it right, the number is " + random);

       } else if (guess<random) {
           System.out.println("You guessed too low!");
           continue;

       } else {
           System.out.println("You guessed too low");
           continue;

       }
   }
```

I get this error whenever I run it. Error:(35, 12) java: continue outside of loop

Comment: What do you expect `continue;` to do?

Comment: There is no loop around like: `while`, `do` or `for`. It can just be used inside a loop.

Comment: I expect it to continue the guess function until someone gets it right.

Comment: "despite it being inside the loop" if statements aren't loops.

Comment: The guess method is a single attempt. There is nothing to continue. You’d need to wrap it in some loop (do/while, while, for, all are fine) to have it try again, and then define an appropriate exit condition (guesses correctly, ran out of tries, user requested to exit).

Comment: Please define: "continue the guess function", which line/statement should be executed *after* `continue` call?

Comment: you probably want a loop to repeat guessing.... then maybe a `continue` can be useful (but probably not needed at all)

Answer (score 1):

From the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16):

> A `continue` statement may occur only in a `while`, `do`, or `for` statement; statements of these three kinds are called *iteration statements*.

You aren't using any of these. `if` statements aren't loops. The compiler isn't lying to you!

If you want to use a `continue`, put a loop around the code you want to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    int random;

    public GuessingGame() {

        generateNumber();

        guess();
    }

    public void generateNumber() {
        // The following lines generate and output a random number between 1 and
        // 10
        random = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    }

    // Write the guess() method below
    public void guess() {
        // Use scanner to accept a user input
        // Create a new scanner object to receive user input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter you guess between 1 to 10");
        int guess = sc.nextInt();

        while (guess != random) {
            // write your code below
            if (guess < random) {
                System.out.println("You guessed too low!");

            } else {
                System.out.println("You guessed too high");

            }
            guess = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("You guessed it right, the number is " + random);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuessingGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, the word continue is only used when inside a loop, and starts the next iteration in the loop without considering the code below the continue statement.
Your error here is that you don't use a loop at all, so the java compiler does not know what to do with the continue statement.

I am assuming you put in the continue to get out of the if statement when you are finished. If so, then you can just remove the continue statements altogether and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the logic you expecting....

```
public class GuessingGame {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int random;

            random = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter you guess between 1 to 10");
            int guess = sc.nextInt();

            while (guess != 0) {
                if (guess < random) {
                    System.out.println("You guessed too low!"+random);
                    System.out.println("Enter you guess between 1 to 10");
                    guess = sc.nextInt();
                    continue;
                } else if (guess > random) {
                    System.out.println("You guessed too High"+random);
                    System.out.println("Enter you guess between 1 to 10");
                    guess = sc.nextInt();
                    continue;
                }else{
                    if (guess == random) {
                        System.out.println("You guessed it right, the number is " + random);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

}
```